# A django like unique together in turbogears/sqlalchemy

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, turbogears

This question essentially two parts.
1. I have a situation where I require things to be unique together i.e the elements in db need to be unique together with each other.

Lets say we have a model Things ( Rough PseudoCode)

```
Class ShoppingList( object ):
     thing1_id = Column(Integer)
     thing2_id = Column(Integer)
```

Now I need thing1_id and thing2_id to be a unique together ie the set of thing1_id and thing2_id needs to be unique together. Coming from django world I know that you can do a meta declaration in django models of unique_together. But how can do this in turbogears .

1. Also how do I actually apply a unique_together on a legacy system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the first part of your question, if I understand your question correctly, I believe you are talking about the need for defining *composite primary keys*.  As stated in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html#describing-databases-with-metadata:

   > Multiple columns may be assigned the primary_key=True flag which denotes a multi-column primary key, known as a composite primary key.

   Defining such a relationship on a class using the declarative ORM way in SQLAlchemy, should be as simple as:

   ```
   class ShoppingList(Base):
       thing1_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
       thing2_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ```
2. As for the second part of your question, I believe you mean how one would define the same SQLAlchemy mapping for an existing, legacy database.  If so, you should be able to use the above approach, just *don't create* the database from the ORM definition.  You may also use the *classic mapping* way, described in: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html?highlight=composite%20primary%20key#classical-mappings

Answer (score 5):

You simply want to add a `UniqueConstraint` to your table definition (using a primary key would achive similar effects, but with different semantics nevertheless).

This is as simple as:

```
Class ShoppingList( object ):
    thing1_id = Column(Integer)
    thing2_id = Column(Integer)

    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('thing1_id', 'thing2_id'),
    )
```

See also https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html#table-configuration